# Visual Studio 2017 Exception Unhandled

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2017, unhandled-exception

I'm a novice programmer trying to follow a tuturial on recreating a game on Steam called Timber(I believe). The program was working fine and I had almost completed the tutrial, but I ran into trouble when I added the code:

```
for (int i = 0 < NUM_BRANCHES; i++;)
{
    branches[i].setTexture(textureBranch);
    branches[i].setPosition(-2000, -2000);
    // Set the sprite's origin to dead center
    // We can then spin it around without changing its position
    branches[i].setOrigin(220, 20);
}
```

Visual Studio says: branches[i].setPosition(-2000, -2000); Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
**this** was 0x59AF28. occurred

I'll also post the full code, apologies that it's a bit messy.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

// Function declaration
void updateBranches(int seed);
const int NUM_BRANCHES = 6;
Sprite branches[NUM_BRANCHES];
// Where is the player/branch?
// Left or right
enum class side{ LEFT, RIGHT, NONE };
side branchPositions[NUM_BRANCHES];

int main()
{
    // Creates a video mode object
    VideoMode vm(1920, 1080);

    // Creates and opens a window for the game
    RenderWindow window(vm, "Timber!!!", Style::Fullscreen);

    // Create a texture to hold a graphic on the GPU
    Texture textureBackground;

    // Load a graphic into the texture
    textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");

    // Create a sprite
    Sprite spriteBackground;

    // Attach the texture to the sprite
    spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);

    // Set the spriteBackground to cover the screen
    spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);

    // Make a tree sprite
    Texture textureTree;
    textureTree.loadFromFile("graphics/tree.png");
    Sprite spriteTree;
    spriteTree.setTexture(textureTree);
    spriteTree.setPosition(810, 0);

    // Prepare the bee
    Texture textureBee;
    textureBee.loadFromFile("graphics/bee.png");
    Sprite spriteBee;
    spriteBee.setTexture(textureBee);
    spriteBee.setPosition(0, 450);

    // Is the be currently moving?
    bool beeActive = false;

    // How fast can the bee fly
    float beeSpeed = 0.0f;

    // Make 3 cloud sprites from 1 texture
    Texture textureCloud;

    // Load 1 new texture
    textureCloud.loadFromFile("graphics/cloud.png");

    // 3 new sprites with the same texture
    Sprite spriteCloud1;
    Sprite spriteCloud2;
    Sprite spriteCloud3;
    spriteCloud1.setTexture(textureCloud);
    spriteCloud2.setTexture(textureCloud);
    spriteCloud3.setTexture(textureCloud);

    // Position the clouds off screen
    spriteCloud1.setPosition(0, 0);
    spriteCloud2.setPosition(0, -150);
    spriteCloud3.setPosition(0, -300);

    // Are the clouds currently on the screen?
    bool cloud1Active = false;
    bool cloud2Active = false;
    bool cloud3Active = false;

    // How fast is each cloud?
    float cloud1Speed = 0.1f;
    float cloud2Speed = 0.2f;
    float cloud3Speed = 0.3f;

    // Variables to control time itself
    Clock clock;

    // Time bar
    RectangleShape timeBar;
    float timeBarStartWidth = 400;
    float timeBarHeight = 80;
    timeBar.setSize(Vector2f(timeBarStartWidth, timeBarHeight));
    timeBar.setFillColor(Color::Red);
    timeBar.setPosition((1920 / 2) - timeBarStartWidth / 2, 980);

    Time gameTimeTotal;
    float timeRemaining = 6.0f;
    float timeBarWidthPerSecond = timeBarStartWidth / timeRemaining;

    // Track whether the game is running
    bool paused = true;

    // Draw some text
    int score = 0;
    sf::Text messageText;
    sf::Text scoreText;

    // Font
    Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("fonts/KOMIKAP_.ttf");

    // Set the font of our message
    messageText.setFont(font);
    scoreText.setFont(font);

    // Assign the actual message
    messageText.setString("Press Enter to Start!");
    scoreText.setString("score = 0");

    // Make text really big
    messageText.setCharacterSize(75);
    scoreText.setCharacterSize(100);

    // Choose a color
    messageText.setFillColor(Color::White);
    scoreText.setFillColor(Color::Black);

    // Position the text
    FloatRect textRect = messageText.getLocalBounds();
    messageText.setOrigin(textRect.left +
        textRect.width / 2.0f,
        textRect.top +
        textRect.height / 2.0f);
    messageText.setPosition(1920 / 2.0f, 1080 / 2.0f);
    scoreText.setPosition(20, 20);

    // Prepare 6 branches
    Texture textureBranch;
    textureBranch.loadFromFile("graphics/branch.png");
    // Set the texture for each branch sprite
    for (int i = 0 < NUM_BRANCHES; i++;)
    {
        branches[i].setTexture(textureBranch);
        branches[i].setPosition(-2000, -2000);
        // Set the sprite's origin to dead center
        // We can then spin it around without changing its position
        branches[i].setOrigin(220, 20);
    }


    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        /*
        **************
        Handles the player input
        **************
        */

        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }

        // Start the game
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Return))
        {
            paused = false;

            // Reset the time and the score
            score = 0;
            timeRemaining = 5;
        }

        /*
        **************
        Update the scene
        **************
        */

        if (!paused)
        {
            // Measure time
            Time dt = clock.restart();

            // Subtract from the amount of time remaining
            timeRemaining -= dt.asSeconds();
            // size up the time bar
            timeBar.setSize(Vector2f(timeBarWidthPerSecond *
                timeRemaining, timeBarHeight));

            if (timeRemaining <= 0.0f)
            {
                // Pause the game
                paused = true;

                // Change the message shown to the player
                messageText.setString("Out of time");

                // Reposition the text base on its new size
                FloatRect textRect = messageText.getLocalBounds();
                messageText.setOrigin(textRect.left +
                    textRect.width / 2.0f,
                    textRect.top +
                    textRect.height / 2.0f);
                messageText.setPosition(1920 / 2.0f, 1080 / 2.0f);
            }

            // Setup the bee
            if (!beeActive)
            {

                // How fast is the bee
                srand((int)time(0) * 10);
                beeSpeed = (rand() % 400) + 350;

                // How high is the bee
                srand((int)time(0) * 10);
                float height = (rand() % 650) + 850;
                spriteBee.setPosition(1921, height);
                beeActive = true;

            }
            else
                // Move the bee
            {

                spriteBee.setPosition(
                    spriteBee.getPosition().x -
                    (beeSpeed * dt.asSeconds()),
                    spriteBee.getPosition().y);

                // Has the bee reached the right hand edge of the screen?
                if (spriteBee.getPosition().x < -100)
                {
                    // Set it up ready to be a whole new bee next frame
                    beeActive = false;
                }

            }

            // Manage the clouds
            // Cloud 1


            if (!cloud1Active)
            {
                // How fast is the cloud
                srand((int)time(0) * 10);
                cloud1Speed = (rand() % 150);

                // How high is the cloud
                srand((int)time(0) * 10);
                float height = (rand() % 200);
                spriteCloud1.setPosition(-300, height);
                cloud1Active = true;

            }

            else
            {
                spriteCloud1.setPosition(
                    spriteCloud1.getPosition().x +
                    (cloud1Speed * dt.asSeconds()),
                    spriteCloud1.getPosition().y);

                // Has the cloud reached the right hand edge of the screen?
                if (spriteCloud1.getPosition().x > 1920)
                {
                    // Set it up ready to be a whole new cloud next frame
                    cloud1Active = false;
                }

            }

            // Cloud 2 


            if (!cloud2Active)
            {
                // How fast is the cloud
                srand((int)time(0) * 20);
                cloud2Speed = (rand() % 200);

                // How high is the cloud
                srand((int)time(0) * 20);
                float height = (rand() % 300);
                spriteCloud2.setPosition(-200, height);
                cloud2Active = true;

            }

            else
            {
                spriteCloud2.setPosition(
                    spriteCloud2.getPosition().x +
                    (cloud1Speed * dt.asSeconds()),
                    spriteCloud2.getPosition().y);

                // Has the cloud reached the right hand edge of the screen?
                if (spriteCloud2.getPosition().x > 1920)
                {
                    // Set it up ready to be a whole new cloud next frame
                    cloud2Active = false;
                }
            }

            // Cloud 3


            if (!cloud3Active)
            {
                // How fast is the cloud
                srand((int)time(0) * 30);
                cloud3Speed = (rand() % 250);

                // How high is the cloud
                srand((int)time(0) * 30);
                float height = (rand() % 150);
                spriteCloud3.setPosition(-100, height);
                cloud3Active = true;

            }

            else
            {
                spriteCloud3.setPosition(
                    spriteCloud3.getPosition().x +
                    (cloud1Speed * dt.asSeconds()),
                    spriteCloud3.getPosition().y);

                // Has the cloud reached the right hand edge of the     screen?
                if (spriteCloud3.getPosition().x > 1920)
                {
                    // Set it up ready to be a whole new cloud next frame
                    cloud3Active = false;
                }
            }

            // Update the score text
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "Score = " << score;
            scoreText.setString(ss.str());

            // Update the branch sprites
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BRANCHES; i++)
            {
                float height = i * 150;
                if (branchPositions[i] == side::LEFT)
                {
                    // Move the sprite to the left side
                    branches[i].setPosition(610, height);
                    // Flip the sprite around the other way
                    branches[i].setRotation(180);
                }
                else if (branchPositions[i] == side::RIGHT)
                {
                    // Move the sprite to the right side
                    branches[i].setPosition(1330, height);
                    // Set the sprite rotation to normal
                    branches[i].setRotation(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Hide the branch
                    branches[i].setPosition(3000, height);
                }
            }

        } // End if(!paused)

        /*
        **************
        Draw the scene
        **************
        */

        // Clear everything from the last frame
        window.clear();

        // Draw our game scene here
        window.draw(spriteBackground);

        // Draw the clouds
        window.draw(spriteCloud1);
        window.draw(spriteCloud2);
        window.draw(spriteCloud3);

        // Draw the branches
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BRANCHES; i++)
        {
            window.draw(branches[i]);
        }

        // Draw the tree
        window.draw(spriteTree);

        // Draw the insect
        window.draw(spriteBee);

        // Draw the score
        window.draw(scoreText);

        //Draw the timebar
        window.draw(timeBar);

        if (paused)
        {
            // Draw our message
            window.draw(messageText);
        }

        // Show everyting we just drew
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

// Function definition
void updateBranches(int seed)
{
    // Move all the branches down on place
    for (int j = NUM_BRANCHES - 1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        branchPositions[j] = branchPositions[j - 1];
    }
    // Spawn a new branch at postion 0
    // LEFt, RIGHT, NONE
    srand((int)time(0) + seed);
    int r = (rand() % 5);
    switch (r)
    {
    case 0:
        branchPositions[0] = side::LEFT;
        break;

    case 1:
        branchPositions[0] = side::RIGHT;
        break;

    default:
        branchPositions[0] = side::NONE;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BRANCHES; i++)`?

Comment: When I try that, Visual Studio tells me that it expected an ';'.

Comment: It's working now, thanks for the help! @mdatsev

Answer (score 0):

setPosition() requires an sf::Vector2f. So you could fix your code by changing that line to:

```
branches[i].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(-2000, -2000))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, but now I get a different error: Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
**this** was 0xCAAF28. occurred

Comment: That'd be from the loop @mdatsev mentioned. I'd suggest double checking that you entered it exactly as he wrote it, since that shouldn't give any errors.